# Divide dataframe rows based on repeat sequence

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an example dataframe below. I am trying to take each sequence of 3 rows and divide the first by the 3rd (or in other words, class "a" by class "c", for every id). What's the most straightforward way to do this? Thanks in advance.

```
 id class value
 0  a   241
 0  b   109
 0  c   350
40  a   239
40  b   160
40  c   399
53  a   158
53  b   97
53  c   255
54  a   239
54  b   78
54  c   317
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `by` to group by **id**, then subset using **value** and **class**:

```
by(data = data, INDICES = data$id, 
   FUN = function(ds) ds[ds$class == "a", "value"] / 
                      ds[ds$class == "c", "value"])
```

This will produce a single value for each **id**. Output:

```
data$id: 0
[1] 0.6885714
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
data$id: 40
[1] 0.5989975
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
data$id: 53
[1] 0.6196078
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
data$id: 54
[1] 0.7539432
```

Comment: That worked - thanks, but I am looking to insert the output as an additional column in the dataframe. Do you know how to coerce the output into a dataframe column?

Comment: Nevermind - figured it out. 

dat<-do.call(rbind, dat) #coerce into dataframe
dat<-rep(dat, each=3)
And then I get slap it back into the original dataframe. 

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution to what I did but this does the trick.Thanks for your great suggestion.

Comment: @SilvanD That is what my first two solutions did elegantly (and also posting it first).  Accepting another solution that is not your required format didn't make sense to me.

Comment: @SilvanD Regarding this solution and using `rep` to fill in the rows work for this example, but consider if the data is nor ordered, i.e. `df1$id[1:3] <- 59`.  Then the output list will be in a different order and then you may need to match the list names and then do the `rep`.

Answer (score 1):

We may try with `split`/`unsplit` from `base R`.  `split` the dataset by 'id' column to get a 'list' output, loop through the list with `lapply`, `transform` the data.frame list element by adding a new column ('value1') based on dividing the 'value' corresponding to 'class' ('a', and 'c'), and `unsplit` by the 'id' column.

```
 unsplit(lapply(split(df1, df1$id), function(x) 
      transform(x, value1= value[class=='a']/value[class=='c'])), df1$id)
 #   id class value    value1
 #1   0     a   241 0.6885714
 #2   0     b   109 0.6885714
 #3   0     c   350 0.6885714
 #4  40     a   239 0.5989975
 #5  40     b   160 0.5989975
 #6  40     c   399 0.5989975
 #7  53     a   158 0.6196078
 #8  53     b    97 0.6196078
 #9  53     c   255 0.6196078
 #10 54     a   239 0.7539432
 #11 54     b    78 0.7539432
 #12 54     c   317 0.7539432
```

Or using `mutate` from `dplyr` to create the new column after grouping by 'id' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
      mutate(value1= value[class=='a']/value[class=='c'])
#    id class value    value1
#1   0     a   241 0.6885714
#2   0     b   109 0.6885714
#3   0     c   350 0.6885714
#4  40     a   239 0.5989975
#5  40     b   160 0.5989975
#6  40     c   399 0.5989975
#7  53     a   158 0.6196078
#8  53     b    97 0.6196078
#9  53     c   255 0.6196078
#10 54     a   239 0.7539432
#11 54     b    78 0.7539432
#12 54     c   317 0.7539432
```

Or if it is based on the location i.e. 1st and last, you can change the last line in the above code by

```
      mutate(value1=first(value)/last(value))
```

Or a compact approach would be to use `data.table`.  The `:=` operator would be very fast in creating the 'value1' column.  Change the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), create the 'value1' column grouped by 'id'.  Here, I selected the 1st (`1L`) and last observation (`.N`) of 'value' assuming that 'a' and 'c' are ordered.  If not ordered, then use `value[class=='a']/value[class=='c']` as before.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, value1:=value[1L]/value[.N] , id]
#   id class value    value1
#1:  0     a   241 0.6885714
#2:  0     b   109 0.6885714
#3:  0     c   350 0.6885714
#4: 40     a   239 0.5989975
#5: 40     b   160 0.5989975
#6: 40     c   399 0.5989975
#7: 53     a   158 0.6196078
#8: 53     b    97 0.6196078
#9: 53     c   255 0.6196078
#10:54     a   239 0.7539432
#11:54     b    78 0.7539432
#12:54     c   317 0.7539432
```

Or another approach using `base R`.  Though, this work on the example dataset, it may not work in situations where the data is not ordered.

```
df1$value1 <- (df1$value[df1$class=='a']/
        df1$value[df1$class=='c'])[as.numeric(factor(df1$id))]
```

#### Update

If you need a single value for each id, replace the `mutate` with `summarise` in `dplyr`

```
 df1 %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(value1= value[class=='a']/value[class=='c'])
 #   id    value1
 #1  0 0.6885714
 #2 40 0.5989975
 #3 53 0.6196078
 #4 54 0.7539432
```

Or remove the assign (`:=`) in `data.table`

```
setDT(df1)[, list(value1=value[class=='a']/value[class=='c']), id]
 #    id    value1
 #1:  0 0.6885714
 #2: 40 0.5989975
 #3: 53 0.6196078
 #4: 54 0.7539432
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 53L, 53L, 53L, 
54L, 54L, 54L), class = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", 
"b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), value = c(241L, 109L, 350L, 239L, 160L, 
399L, 158L, 97L, 255L, 239L, 78L, 317L)), .Names = c("id", "class", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer, akrun. I'm not very familiar with dplyr, but it seems like it's worthwhile to become more so!  I haven't had much success with your answer, however.  It keeps returning: Error: incompatible size (%d), expecting %d (the group size) or 1

Comment: @SIlvanD I updated with the dataset I used.  I am not getting any error using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`